# Use method reference to check boolean value match instead of lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

Use of Method reference for comparing `boolean`.

Instead of `(t->t)`, I want to use method reference. Method reference is applicable for non-boolean value match as stated below.

Full Code:

```
public class AccountListTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<Account> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Account a1 = new Account(true, "Test1");
        list.add(a1);
        Account a2 = new Account(false, "Test2");
        list.add(a2);

        if(list.stream().map(Account::getName).anyMatch("test1"::equalsIgnoreCase)){
            System.out.println("Contain Account with name Test1");
        }

        if(list.stream().map(Account::isActive).anyMatch(t->t)){
            System.out.println("Have Active Account");
        }
    }
}

class Account{
    private boolean active;
    private String name;
    public Account(boolean active, String name) {
        super();
        this.active = active;
        this.name = name;
    }   
}
```

Any help is appreciated! thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would make more sense to write the second condition as:

```
if(list.stream().anyMatch(Account::isActive)) {
    System.out.println("Have Active Account");
}
```

There's no need to call `map` first.

Comment: true but how to use anyMatch with exclamation symbol
if(list.stream().anyMatch(Account::!isActive)) {
    System.out.println("Have closed Account");
}

Comment: @SKumar you cannot, either use a lambda expression `(a -> !a.isActive())` or define a `isInActive()` method in your Account class and use that method.

Comment: @SKumar `if( ! list.stream().allMatch(Account::isActive)) {
    System.out.println("Have closed Account");
}` Starting with JDK 11, you could also use `if(list.stream().anyMatch(Predicate.not(Account::isActive))) {
    System.out.println("Have closed Account");
}`

Answer (score 3):

As has been pointed out your best options, depending on your needs, are:

```
list.stream().allMatch(Account::isActive)
list.stream().anyMatch(Account::isActive)
!list.stream().noneMatch(Account::isActive)
```

and so on.

But to directly answer your question, you could use:

```
list.stream().map(Account::isActive).anyMatch(Boolean::valueOf)
```

Comment: The closest equivalent would be `.anyMatch(Boolean.TRUE::equals)` but being a close equivalent is not really an advantage here.

Comment: @Holger yep fair point I'll remove the 'closest functional equivalent' comment